# Powershell new-ADUser Issue

Tags: server, windows-server-2012, powershell-4.0

```
$userarray = import-csv "userlist.csv"

foreach ($user in $userarray){
    $login = $user.username
    $gname = $user.firstname
    $sname = $user.lastname
    $fname = $gname + " " + $sname
    $passw = ConvertTo-SecureString $user.password -AsPlainText -Force
    $email = $user.email
    $dptmt = $user.department
    $hodir = "\\BYFS01\Home$\$login"
    $madou = "OU=$dptmt,OU=Staff,DC=breezeyob.v11a,DC=.org"

    New-ADUser -SamAccountName $login -UserPrincipalName $email     -Name     $fname -GivenName $gname -Surname $sname -EmailAddress $email     -AccountPassword $passw -Enabled 1 -Path $madou -HomeDrive "Z:"     -HomeDirectory $hodir
```

}

That is my current code. My CSV has all the correct headings, they're also in order.

The error's I get when I run this are (Happens for each user, nothing gets inputted into AD- Users and computers:

[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF7ru.png)

So my question is, why am I getting this error? If you wish to see my CSV let me know!

Answer (score 0):

The following are the problem children of your command:

```
$email = $user.email
$madou = "OU=$dptmt,OU=Staff,DC=breezeyob.v11a,DC=.org"
```

The help for the command suggests that the value needs to be constant. The issue comes from $email's dependency on another variable, $user. The variable $user is in turn dependent on *another* variable, $userarray. This many variables within variables is unstable (from a PowerShell perspective).

Try attaining a value like the following for your $email variable *before* you initialize it in your ad-hoc HashTable:

```
$email = 'email@company.org'
```

Note that you do not have to have it *explicitly* stated like my example. It can be like this as well:

```
$email = $anotherVariable
```

The key here is that $anothervariable point to a value like

```
'email@company.org'
```

And not something like

```
"email@$DontKnowThisYetVariable.org"
```

Consider the following:

```
$login = $user.username
```

This statement is most likely not causing any issues because your variable '$user.username' points to a string constant like "Calvin" or "Hobbes" somewhere in your CSV.

I am confident that if your variables point to constant values, your command will run smoothly. I reproduced the same error when I created a quick-and-dirty Active Directory Domain. I ran the following in my super new AD Domain and it worked:

```
$userarray = Import-Csv "userlist.csv"

$DefinedVariable = "Users"

foreach ($user in $userarray){

$login = $user.username
$gname = $user.firstname
$sname = $user.lastname
$fname = $gname + " " + $sname
$passw = ConvertTo-SecureString $user.password -AsPlainText -Force
$email = $user.email
$dptmt =  $DefinedVariable

$madou = "CN=$dptmt,DC=contoso,DC=com"

New-ADUser -SamAccountName $login -UserPrincipalName $email -Name $fname  -GivenName $gname `
-Surname $sname -EmailAddress $email -AccountPassword $passw -Enabled $true `
-Path $madou -HomeDrive "Z:" -HomeDirectory $hodir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just the syntax of the $madou variable:
As far as I know the DistinguishedName attribute doesn't allow dots (.) in its string. So I think, instead of:

```
$madou = "OU=$dptmt,OU=Staff,DC=breezeyob.v11a,DC=.org"
```

It should be:

```
$madou = "OU=$dptmt,OU=Staff,DC=breezeyob,DC=v11a,DC=org"
```